# How to use mkdir with xargs

Tags: bash, mkdir, xargs

i am new to xargs..

i want to use mkdir with xargs to create some folders similar to:

```
for i in {1..11};do mkdir mm$i;done
```

which will create folders mm1, mm2, mm2 ... mm11

i tried:

```
echo {1..11}|xargs -p -n1 -I {} mkdir -p "mm{}"
```

however it prompt:

```
mkdir -p mm1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ?...
```

i also tried:

```
echo {1..11}|xargs -p -n1 mkdir -p mm
```

it prompt:

```
mkdir -p mm 1 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 2 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 3 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 4 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 5 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 6 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 7 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 8 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 9 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 10 ?...n
mkdir -p mm 11 ?...n
mkdir -p mm ?...n
```

help..
tks

Comment: Don't use `xargs`, use `mkdir mm{1..11}`.

Comment: tks!! n i just use for........
bw wonder what will work with xargs, coz sed work this way, but mkdir not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the `-I` flag, which requires that
arguments be separated by blank lines rather than whitespace:

```
-I replace-str
       Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
       names  read  from  standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not
       terminate input items; instead  the  separator  is  the  newline
       character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

One solution is to generate appropriate input:

```
echo {1..11} | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs ...
```

Or:

```
seq 11 | xargs ...
```

Or, as  @gniourf_gniourf suggests in the comment, just use shell
expansion directly for this particular case.

Comment: I thought the -n flag help adding the nextline